# Get product collection as per store currency in magento2

Tags: magento2, product, multistore, frontend

I want to get product collection as per store vise.

Currently, I created 2 store

**1) IN , 2) US.**

In IN set INR and in US set USD. By default store is US.

When I change store and set IN then product price I get in USD in product collection.

How can i get product collection price in INR in product collection when store is IN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of that get product collection :-

```
<?php
namespace ABC\HelloWorld\Block;
class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {    
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->setPageSize(3); // fetching only 3 products
        return $collection;
    }
}
?>
```

Then use this block in your phtml and get price as per store vise currency :

```
    $productCollection = $block->getProductCollection();
    foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
        $price=$objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency(number_format($product->getPrice(),2));// store wise value can change with currency.
    }
```

Hope it is useful for other.